# PHP sending blank information to the database

Tags: php, mysql, unity-game-engine, isset

I am using a Unity form in conjunction with PHP to send data to a database, I can successfully enter information in and it reaches the database but the problem is it also sends the data if the fields are empty.

I am trying to prevent this using the isset method but it doesn't appear to be working. Can somebody double check this for me?

Image of data reaching the database

[image]

Image of unity form

[image]

```
<?php

    if(!isset($_POST['usernamePost'], $_POST['passwordPost'], $_POST['emailPost']))
    {
        echo "This is not working";
    }
    else
    {
    //Enter the data into the database
    $username = filter_var($_POST['usernamePost'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $password = filter_var($_POST['passwordPost'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email = filter_var($_POST['emailPost'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    //variable for connection
    $servername = "localhost";
    $server_username = "root";
    $server_password = "";
    $dbName = "ontrigger_game";

        try
        {
            //connection to the database
            $dbhandle = mysqli_connect($servername, $server_username, $server_password) 
              or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
            echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";

            //select a database to work with
            $selected = mysqli_select_db($dbhandle, $dbName)
                    or die("Could not select database");

            $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email)
                VALUES ('".$username."','".$password."','".$email."')";
            if(!mysqli_query($dbhandle, $sql))
            {
              die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
            }
            echo "1 record added";

            //close the connection
            mysqli_close($dbhandle);

        } 
        catch (Exception $ex) 
        {

        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: be carefull to sql injections...

Comment: **Never** store plain text passwords. Instead use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). If you're using a version of PHP prior to 5.5, do **not** use MD5 or SHA1 to hash passwords. Instead you can use [this compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` does not protect against [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use prepared statements with bound parameters, via either the [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) drivers. [**This post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has some good examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also check if its empty by using the `empty()` method

```
if (!isset($_POST['usernamePost']) && empty($_POST['usernamePost'] )) {

// error message here

} else {

// What you want to do if not empty and is set.

}
```

Note: Use the `&&` operator instead of comma's